# ORing N-bit input to get 1-bit output

Tags: logic

[Design_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aEkG.png)

As in the graph, is this possible? 
So I am trying to check if the N-bit input is zero or not.

I thought of doing this, ORing every bit in N-bit and then following it with Not-gate, and so if all bits are zero, Or gate would generate a 0 output, but yet I am not sure, would how would OR-gate access every bit? I am really confused! How to OR every bit in the N-bit? How does it work? without knowing whats N?
And how can I check if the most significant bit is 1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use shift operator along with & operator (concept of masking with 1). Right shift the bits until the number becomes 0 and in each step do Anding with 1.Check at each step if the result after Anding with 1 is 0 or non zero.

Comment: Thank you! 
I just noticed that the slash means that the bit-lines are parallel so we can access any bit anytime .. so it is easy to OR all the bits.